# Redis-Latency : in our project facing redis latency on standalone server installation

Tags: java, performance, redis

facing latency in redis,below redis-benchmarh and -cli results indicates latency in redis. need recommendation on what configuration needs to be revisited and what could be the possible approaches to reduce latencies.

- **executed ./redis-benchmark**

PING_INLINE: 45516.61 requests per second
PING_BULK: 45189.57 requests per second
SET: 44259.54 requests per second
GET: 43782.84 requests per second
INCR: 44970.10 requests per second
LPUSH: 44941.80 requests per second
RPUSH: 44066.45 requests per second
LPOP: 44023.77 requests per second
RPOP: 44395.12 requests per second
SADD: 45214.09 requests per second
HSET: 44953.92 requests per second 
SPOP: 46405.87 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 45036.93 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 6246.02 requests per second
^CANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 2597.04

====== SET ====== 
1000000 requests completed in 23.26 seconds

50 parallel clients 
3 bytes payload 
keep alive: 1 
host configuration "save": 120 1 60 10 30 50 
host configuration "appendonly": no 
multi-thread: no

0.06% <= 0.1 milliseconds 
0.12% <= 0.2 milliseconds 
0.29% <= 0.3 milliseconds 
2.74% <= 0.4 milliseconds 
10.03% <= 0.5 milliseconds 
20.61% <= 0.6 milliseconds 
33.12% <= 0.7 milliseconds 
46.25% <= 0.8 milliseconds 
58.20% <= 0.9 milliseconds 
68.19% <= 1.0 milliseconds 
76.34% <= 1.1 milliseconds 
82.77% <= 1.2 milliseconds 
87.68% <= 1.3 milliseconds 
91.35% <= 1.4 milliseconds 
93.95% <= 1.5 milliseconds 
95.73% <= 1.6 milliseconds 
96.94% <= 1.7 milliseconds 
97.73% <= 1.8 milliseconds 
98.26% <= 1.9 milliseconds 
98.62% <= 2 milliseconds 
99.39% <= 3 milliseconds 
99.55% <= 4 milliseconds 
99.71% <= 5 milliseconds 
99.83% <= 6 milliseconds 
99.89% <= 7 milliseconds 
99.93% <= 8 milliseconds 
99.95% <= 9 milliseconds 
99.97% <= 10 milliseconds 
99.98% <= 11 milliseconds 
99.98% <= 12 milliseconds 
99.98% <= 13 milliseconds 
99.98% <= 14 milliseconds 
99.98% <= 17 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 79 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 80 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 96 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 97 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 107 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 108 milliseconds 
99.99% <= 109 milliseconds 
100.00% <= 536 milliseconds 
100.00% <= 537 milliseconds 
100.00% <= 539 milliseconds 
100.00% <= 539 milliseconds

42992.26 requests per second

** - Executed - $ ./redis-cli --latency **

min: 0, max: 366, avg: 0.57 (3960 samples)^C

** - **Redis-Configuration** **

tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
supervised no
loglevel notice
save 120 1
save 60 10
save 30 50
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
rdb-del-sync-files no
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-diskless-load disabled
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
maxclients 10000
maxmemory 25gb
maxmemory-policy noeviction
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
lazyfree-lazy-user-del no
io-threads 3
appendonly no
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-max-len 1000
latency-monitor-threshold 0
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 2gb 256mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 256mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
jemalloc-bg-thread yes

**Exception coming :**

As checked in logs Following exception is logged in logs:

1. ```
          org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command still hasn't been written into connection! Increase nettyThreads and/or retryInterval settings. Payload size in bytes: 87.
   ```
2. ```
          Redis server response timeout (30000 ms) occured after 5 retry attempts. Increase nettyThreads and/or timeout settings. Try to define pingConnectionInterval setting. Command: (XREAD), params: [STREAMS,
   ```